# How to use place holders in python dictionary?

Tags: python, api, dictionary, python-requests

```
val1 = "some_value"
list_of_key2_values = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]    
test_data = {"abcd": [{"key1": [],
                           "key2": [{
                                       "key2_1": "value2_1",
                                       "key2_2": ""
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }
```

template of test_data mentioned above. I don't think I can use place holders here.
How can i replace the values of template as mentioned below ?

```
test_data = {"abcd": [{"key1": ["some_value],
                           "key2": [{
                                       "key2_1": "value2_1",
                                       "key2_2": "string1"
                                        },
                                     {
                                       "key2_1": "value2_1",
                                       "key2_2": "string2"
                                        },
                                     {
                                       "key2_1": "value2_1",
                                       "key2_2": "string3"
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                }
```

This is the data I would like to load to api execution. Can you please help me ?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're asking here. I gather the "placeholders" you're referring to are the empty list for `key1` and the empty strings in the `key2` structure, but how much do you know about those datastructures in advance? Is the organization of `test_data` something you can hard-code around or do you need to be searching it for the things to replace? If the latter, how do you know what gets replaced where?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Blckknght , yes, it's key1 value to be restored from string, And key2_2 value to be stored from list respectively forming the list of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of `test_data` is fixed, you can pretty easily write code to put the missing values into the places you want them:

```
test_data["abcd"][0]["key1"].append(val1)

test_data["abcd"][0]["key2"] = [{"key2_1": "value2_1",
                                 "key2_2": val}
                                for val in list_of_key2_values]
```

Now, this hard-codes a lot of information about the structure of the `test_data` object and its various levels of nesting. If you need code that can support any kind of structure, then you'll need to be a lot more careful about defining how you find and identify the places your data are going to go. Your question as it stands isn't specific enough to make it clear you want to add your single `val1` into the empty list under `"key1"` and that you want to put the values in `list_of_key2_values` into copies of the dictionary under `"key2"` replacing the empty strings. For a one-off hard-coded solution, I could deduce that requirement from the desired output, but a generic function would need the rules to be more precisely specified.

Comment: Thanks @Blackkngt. But do we have any other better approach ?

Comment: If you wanted a more generic solution, you'd need to specify better where the values get substituted into the unknown data structure. For instance, maybe `"key1"` wouldn't correspond to an empty list value, but to a list containing `["{{val1}}"]`, and the logic might be to replace the string with that kind of bracket notation with the value from the variable. Code to do that would not be trivial, but it's not impossibly difficult either, just moderately complex. And you might not need it, so don't feel like you need to avoid hard-coding if you only have a limited need for this.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I tried with place holders '{}' but did not work. How can I do this ?

Comment: That's a lot more complicated than I can deal with in a comment here. Perhaps you should ask a second question about that? Try to specify the details of what kind of substitutions you might need, then we can figure out what code is needed to do it. I'd say the specification needs to identify the keys that need values (e.g. `key1` and `key2` in your examples), and where the specific values need to be inserted (e.g. in the list under `key1`, and in place of the empty string in the sub-structure under `key2`.